# Using a bash script to write current date to a .cfg/text file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, date

I'm trying to get the current date as month/day (i.e., 6/18), printed into a .cfg file (using sed because I need a specific line changed). However, when running the bash, the date is correct in the output but when checking the file it's printing the command not the date. Any suggestions?

```
sed -i -- 's/^example=.*/example="$(date)"/g' /path/to/config.cfg
```

Also, date is just printing the full date (Thu June 18 19:34:14 EDT 2020), I just need the month/day.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell never expands anything inside a single quoted string.

You will have to use a double quoted string for your `sed` expression:

```bsh
sed -i "s,^\(example=\).*,\1$(date +%m/%d)," /path/to/config.cfg
```

Alternatively, use two single quoted strings with the command substitution in double quotes between them:

```bsh
sed -i 's,^\(example=\).*,\1'"$(date +%m/%d)"',' /path/to/config.cfg
```

Alternatively, let `date` output the `sed` expression:

```bsh
sed -i "$(date +'s,^\(example=\).*,\1%m/%d,')" /path/to/config.cfg
```

(but this looks a bit awkward).

I turned the expression a bit shorter by means of a back-reference for the `example=` text.  I'm using `,` as the delimiter for the `s///` command in `sed` because we're dealing with a string in the replacement part that contains a `/` character (the alternative would have been to use `%m\\/%d` as the format string with `date` to generate an escaped `/` character).

Note that the double quotes around the command substitution are not needed in the first variation of the command above as the whole `sed` expression is quoted. Also, the `/g` at the end of the `s///` command is not needed as you can't expect the pattern to match more than once, since it's anchored to the start of the line.  I've also removed the `--` that you used.  Some `sed` implementations would almost certainly have used that string as the backup suffix, i.e. as the option-argument to the `-i` option (e.g. `sed` on macOS).

I'm using `date +%m/%d` to generate the wanted date format.  This would generate `06/19` for today's date. Would you not want zero-filled numbers for the day, use `%e` in place of `%d` (see `man strftime`). There does not appear to be a standard format for getting the month without zero filling the number, but if you use GNU `date` you may use the non-standard `%-m` format (i.e. `date +%-m/%e`, see `man date`).

Comment: Thank you so much @Kusalananda. Not only did you solve my problem, you also educated me in a clear/understandable manner. I greatly appreciate it.